# Manually Editing Codename One (Old) UI Designer Built Project

Tags: codenameone

I have a project that I built with the old Codename One UI Designer. It has many 'SpanButtons' that I need to change for 'Buttons'. I don't want to have to do this using the Designer tool as it will involve a lot of work. Which files should I manually edit to make the change?

Answer (score 1):

This wouldn't be much simpler with the old designer...

You can migrate to the new GUI builder which will be a lot of work.

Alternatively you can try this but a word of warning you would want to backup everything...

Turn on `File` -> `XML Team Mode` then save and close the designer. Open all the relevant `.ui` files under the res directory and edit them appropriately.

Open the top level XML file of the resource file (usually `theme.xml`) and set the attribute `useXmlUI=true` in the top tag.

Finally reopen the res file in the designer and save.

Comment: I tried editing the files following your procedure but it did not work. I edited the .ui files, changing all occurrences of 'SpanButton' to 'Button' and saved but when I opened designer it still showed SpanButtons. When I saved the designer again the .ui files had all reverted to show 'SpanButtons' again. The designer does not seem to load directly from the .ui files.

Comment: I neglected the portion about `useXmlUI` you also need that step of the .ui files to be read otherwise they are write only.

Comment: Still not working for me. I get a number of 'Error creating component: xxxxxx java.lang.NullPointerException trying to recover dialogs when opening the designer. When the designer opens most of the forms are missing / corrupted.

Comment: Yes once you get an exception that will be the case try running the designer from the command line and see the exceptions you get https://www.codenameone.com/blog/using-designer-command-line-options.html I'm guessing that the syntax for the `button` component is probably different than the `SpanButton` and you need to adapt the custom properties to match the builtin properties.